# regex to validate AS Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, jakarta-ee

I need a regular expression to validate a web form field that should contain an AS number in `asdot` notation as explained in [RFC 5396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5396#page-2):

> asdot
>
> ```
>   refers to a syntax scheme of representing AS number values less
>   than 65536 using asplain notation and representing AS number
>   values equal to or greater than 65536 using asdot+ notation.
>   Using asdot notation, an AS number of value 65526 would be
>   represented as the string "65526" and an AS number of value 65546
>   would be represented as the string "1.10".
> ```

I want to use [Javascript RegExp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and Java EE [javax.validation.constraints.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) with regex.

Comment: This hardly differs from validating a positive number with an optional decimal part. What have you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: @tripleee I have tried some things, but I am not a regex expert and I found that testing simple numeric ranges is so difficult (http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Javascript regex that should do what you require:

```
/^([1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5])(\.([1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5]|0))?$/
```

Assumptions:
Numbers beginning `0.` are disallowed.
Numbers with a zero after the dot are allowed as I presume e.g. that `65536` is represented as `1.0`. 
Leading zeros are not allowed in the number after the dot e.g. `1.00009` is invalid.
The maximum value of a 4-byte AS number is `4294967295` which is `65536*65535 + 65535`, i.e. `65535.65535` in asdot notation.

As Javascript RegExp oject:

```
var asdot = new RegExp("^([1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|65[0-4]\\d{2}|655[0-2]\\d|6553[0-5])(\\.([1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|65[0-4]\\d{2}|655[0-2]\\d|6553[0-5]|0))?$");

console.log( asdot.test('65535.65535') )   // true
```

As Java Pattern:

```
Pattern asdot = Pattern.compile("^([1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|65[0-4]\\d{2}|655[0-2]\\d|6553[0-5])(\\.([1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|65[0-4]\\d{2}|655[0-2]\\d|6553[0-5]|0))?$");

System.out.println( asdot.matcher("65535.65535").matches() );    // true
```

Comment: tested. simply epic!! thank you very much, it is just what I want. your assumptions are all true based on RFC 5396.